# Importing variables gives attribute error python

Tags: python, variables, import, attributeerror

This is done in python 2.7.3:

x.py:

```
import y
global path_variable
path_variable = "a_path"
y.procedure()
```

y.py:

```
import x
def procedure():
    return x.path_variable
```

Now when I run X I get this odd error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'path_variable'
```

Why is this? As far as I know python allows you import variables. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is just an issue of circular dependency. Basically, you can fix this code but you probably want to rethink your package design such that you don't have two modules which import one another.

Also, you don't need to declare `path_variable` as `global` as it is only used when changing variables in global scope while inside local scope and its use is also generally discouraged in Python.

**x.py**

```
import y
path_variable = "a_path"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    y.procedure()
```

**y.py**

```
import x
def procedure():
    return x.path_variable
```

Comment: That's not the entire code. So x is global for a reason. I just thought I'd say it was global, too see if it would make a difference.